# Cron Job con laravel una ayudita porfa

Tags: php, html, laravel

Buenas a todos haber si podéis echarme una mano porque ando un poco perdido. Estoy creando un Cron Job para que se encienda y se apague una vela. Al pasar x tiempo que se apague la vela. Yo lo estoy probando al pasar 1 minuto pues que se apague para hacer pruebas mas rápido. Pero no hay manera de conseguirlo... os dejo el código por aquí haber si alguien puede echarme una mano. Gracias!!

Este es el comando:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\WhiteCandle;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class WhiteCandleOff extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'off:candle';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Change to OFF white_candles database';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        WhiteCandle::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinute(1))->where('on_off', WhiteCandle::ON)->update(['on_off' => WhiteCandle::OFF]);
        
       
    }
}
```

Esto es el Kernel:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('off:candle')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Nose si esta frase la estoy escribiendo correctamente o me falta algo?

WhiteCandle::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinute(1))->where('on_off', WhiteCandle::ON)->update(['on_off' => WhiteCandle::OFF]);

WhiteCandle::ON y WhiteCandle::OFF son unas constantes que estoy pasando corresponden a 1 y a 0

Comment: Tenés configurado el cronjob para que ejecute el comando schedule:run cada 1 minuto? Hiciste algún log para saber si tu comando se está ejecutando? Cuál es exactamente el comportamiento que tiene lo que muestras, o que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ esto es exactamente lo que no funciona: WhiteCandle::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinute(1))

Todo lo otro lo probé y si que funciona. Mi idea es que al pasar 1 minuto de su creacion que cambie el valor de on_off a 0

Comment: Esa columna on_off está en el array de la propiedad `$fillable` del modelo? Prodrias hacer un log de esa consulta `Log::debug(WhiteCandle::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinute(1))->where('on_off', WhiteCandle::ON)->count());` y comentar que te devuelve

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I don't put fillables or guards at the moment... this is what returns with Log::debug:

[2022-07-19 22:29:56] local.DEBUG: 0

Comment: Nose prk te he respondido en ingles jajajajajajja perdona! 
NO he puesto ningun fillable ni guard aun... Esto es lo que me retorna Log::debug: [2022-07-19 22:29:56] local.DEBUG: 0
Gracias por la ayuda porcierto!

Comment: Ok. No estoy totalmente seguro en este momento, pero creo que para que funcione el update de eloquent, tienes que agregar la columna a fillable. De todas maneras la consulta te está devolviendo 0 registros para esas condiciones. O sea, según eloquent, no hay ningún registro donde el valor la columna created_at sea menor a ahora menos un minuto y donde el valor de la columna on_off sea "verdadero". Prueba con `Log::debug(WhiteCandle::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinute(1))->where('on_off', WhiteCandle::ON)->toSql());` para ver cómo traduce tu consulta eloquent a sql.

Comment: Además, asegurate de que en BD tengas algún registro que compla esas condiciones

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Era el timezone! compi muchas gracias por tu tiempo y por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue añadir el timezone de mi pais ya que el cronjob se ejecutaba como si fuera de otra zona horaria.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).